# Why does my .NET ActiveX control fail to register in Internet Explorer?

Tags: .net, activex, com-interop, dllregistration, activexobject

I am writing an ActiveX control to run in Internet Explorer.  I am using C# and the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace.

When I register the control manually on my development machine using `regasm`, the control works and I can invoke methods on it using Javascript's `new ActiveXObject(..)` functionality.

However, for production I want to embed the object in my page using an `<OBJECT>` tag, and this is where I am having trouble.

The ActiveX DLL is failing to register, and when I inspect the ActiveX registration error messages (using the Code Download Error Log Viewer), I see the following:

**OCX Registration: no DllRegisterServer entry point in (path to my control.dll). Skipping registration.**

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?  Does my C# code require methods to perform a `DllRegisterServer` action?  Can ActiveX controls developed in .NET be used in this way?

Many thanks.

Comment: I  think, the message "OCX Registration: no DllRegisterServer entry point" ponts to a registration-attempt via RegSrv32 (or some equivalent api-call). You will need some regasm-call BEFORE using the control on your page.

Comment: Ok... is it possible to get IE to invoke Regasm to register the assembly instead of RegSrv32?

Answer (score 0):

If by "production" you mean the public Internet, and you want your page to automatically download and register the ActiveX control, you'll need to do some special packaging as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1330658/137646) to the question "How do you deploy an ActiveX control for ie from a VS2008 project?"

However, if your production environment is an intranet, you can use [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) to register your assembly and then use gacutil.exe to install it in the GAC (as described in the article).